# ORDER BY только 5 первых результатов

Tags: php, mysql

такая комбинация:

```
ORDER by first DESC,second DESC
```

сортирует в первую очередь по значению *first*, во вторую очередь по значению *second*.

как сделать, чтобы по первому значению сортировались только 5 элементов, остальные же сортировались по *second*?

Comment: Похоже Вам понадобится GROUP BY и/или под SELECTю Пожалуйста, добавьте весь sql запроса, а также выходящие данные, и что ожидается получить

Answer (score 1):

Рецепт громоздкий, но каков вопрос, таков и ответ.

Мы "разрежем" отсортированную по `first` таблицу на две части с помощью LIMIT. Обе части затем "склеим" обратно через UNION ALL, но перед этим проделаем подготовительную работу:

- Добавим сортировочное поле в обе части.
- В одной части значение нового поля должно совпадать с `second`, а в другой части должно быть гарантированно больше (или меньше) любого реального значения из `second`.
- Результат склейки отсортируем по двум полям в приоритете: `новое поле`, затем поле `first`.

Итог выглядит так:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
  (
    (SELECT '' AS `fix`, t1.*
     FROM `mytable` AS t1
     ORDER BY t1.`first` LIMIT 3)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT t2.`second` AS `fix`, t2.*
     FROM `mytable` AS t2
     ORDER BY t2.`first` LIMIT 3,1000000)
  ) AS t
ORDER BY t.`fix`, t.`first`
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d4da7/1
[image]

**UPDATE:**
Если заранее знаем те несколько значений `first`, которые должны быть первыми, то мы можем здо́рово упростить запрос! Просто перечислим нужное через запятую:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `mytable` AS t
ORDER BY IF(t.`first` IN(1,2,3), '', `second`), t.`first`
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d4da7/2

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, через временную таблицу. Но не уверен, что правильно получилось

```
drop temporary table if exists table2;

create temporary table if not exists table2 as (select * from table1 order by first desc limit 5);

(select * from table2)
    union
(select * from table1 where id not in (select id from table2) order by second;

drop temporary table if exists table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, чисто как идея, можно попробовать что-то вроде подобной конструкции:

```
SET @rn = 0;
SELECT r.*
FROM (
    SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 as rn, t.*
    FROM table t
    ORDER BY t.first desc
) r
ORDER BY CASE WHEN r.rn <= 5 THEN r.first else 0 END DESC, r.second DESC
```

Но тут надо понимать, какие типы данных используются, т.к. в зависимости от этого запрос может быть изменен.